# What is the maximum overshoot of interpolating splines in $d$ dimensions?

Tags: interpolation, spline

Consider cubic splines $s( x, y )$ which interpolate values $y = \{ y_0, y_1, \dots,y_n \}$,
on the uniform grid $\{ 0, 1,\dots, n \}$.
Fix $s''(0) = s''(n) = 0$ (natural splines).
How big can

$$\operatorname{overshoot}( s; y )  \equiv \max_{0\le x\le n} s( x; y ) $$

be, over all splines $s( x; y )$ and all $0 \le y_i\le 1$?
Interpolating a pulse $[ 0\, 0\, 1\, 1\, 0\, 0 ]$ with Catmull-Rom splines overshoots to $\frac98$;
in $d$ dimensions, a "mesa" $[ 0\, 0\, 1\, 1\, 0\, 0 ]^d$ will overshoot to $({9 \over 8})^d$.

[image]

Can anyone point me to an upper bound for overshoot
of tensor-product cubic splines on grids of integers in $d$ dimensions ?
Or for quadratic splines ?

(Note that overshoot() is here defined as a max over $0 \le y_i\le 1$,
half that over $-1 \le y_i \le 1$.)

Interpolating splines can be local or global.
(Local C-R splines look at $4^d$ nearest neighbors of each $x$;
IIR splines, described in Unser with IIR filters and implemented in scipy.ndimage,
have infinite support.)
With scipy's global IIR splines I see about twice the overshoot of local C-R:

[image]

References:

M. Unser, [Splines: A perfect fit for signal and image processing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.6706&rep=rep1&type=pdf) ,
1999, 17p .
[scipy.ndimage interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#interpolation-functions) .
Wikipedia [Bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)
mentions overshoot, haloing, and ringing artifacts in 2d images.

Comment: I'd like to know the same and I asked a similar question on MathOverflow a while ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201004/estimating-overshoot-in-spline-interpolation. Sadly, this seems to be completely unknown.

Comment: Years later. Still a mystery.